# DynamoDB create another table for query a list attribute in a table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am inheriting DynamoDB from someone.

There is a table called **Item**. It used an item id as a partition key which is also primary key(no sort key in this table).

Each item has a **Tags** attribute which is a list like tag1, tag2, etc. Now, I got a new use case that I want to query item by tags efficiently. What is the best solution to this?

I am thinking creating another table for **Tags** which will be a partition key and item id becomes its sort key. Is it the best solution besides re-designing **Item** table?

```
Partition key(Primary key)   tags.           name        other attributes....
 
id1                          t1,t2.          Item1Name    ... 
id2                          t1,t3,t4,t5.    Item2Name    ...
...
```

My idea is to create another table, is it the best solution? any idea is appreciated.

```
Partition key(Primary key)   sort key     
 
t1                           id1
t1                           id2        
t2                           id1
t3                           id2
t4                           id2
t5                           id2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would require you to recreate the table and take the benefit of using a [GSI (Global Secondary Index)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

If you create the DynamoDB table to have a partition of primary key and then then a sort key of the tag then the data associated with the row you would perform a query like normal to retrieve based on your ID.

You would then create a GSI with the partition key of the tag (and perhaps sort key as the id assuming you need it) along with [projecting any attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections) you would want available to the GSI.

This approach is better than attempting to manage data between 2 seperate DynamoDB tables as you will only have to make the change once but can retrieve the data easily for both scenarios.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for replying. If re-creating the table and using tag as a sort key, does it mean it will have duplicate data for same item id but different tags? If I want to update other attributes dor an item, I have to update all items with same ids and different tags?

Comment: If you want to retrieve via a specific tag then yes you would unfortunately (although in NoSQL [denormalised is the approach you take](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/should-your-dynamodb-table-be-normalized-or-denormalized/)), I guess the conflict is whether you want to manage 1 or 2 tables and how you handle if they become out of sync. :)